# is there a way to track when others have commented on my answers on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, notifications, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I looked through the FAQ page but there was no answer there. Say I post an answer to a question. Then someone else wrote a comment to my post. How do I know a comment is posted without clicking through all my responses?

Answer (score 2):

May I point you towards the [Global Inbox](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/)?

Essentially, when an a comment is left to one of your answers the StackExchange link (upper left, above the Stack Overflow icon) will have a number, with a distinctive red background-colour appended to it to show the number of comments/responses.

Comment: Global Inbox has a distinct lack of envelope.

Comment: @corsiKa: this is true. Forgive me: but I think I'm missing your point..?

Comment: I assume that was a ["waah, who moved my cheese?"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/) comment.